# SQL select from table where column contains specific strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have a table which contains strings which is needed to be searched [like below image]

[image: search table] TableA

After that, I have a table which stores data [like below image]

[image] TableB

And what the search function does is to select from TableB only if the record contains the string in TableA [i.e. The expected result should be like below image(TableC)]

[image] TableC

I've tried using the SQL below, but the SQL had some error while trying to run [`Incorrect syntax near 'select'`] , also, the SQL is a bit complicated, is there any way to make the SQL simplier?

```
select * from TableB a 
where exists 
    (select colA from TableB b 
        where b.colA = a.ColA and Contains (b.ColA, select searchCol from TableA))
```

Comment: I am not exactly sure of the answer, but I think you'll have to use `LIKE` on table two, where the expressions you take will be from table 1.

Comment: but how to "Like" multiple values for searching?

Comment: Contains functions requires text in second argument. You cant use Select in it. Some info here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(CONTAINS_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try:

```
select 
  a.* 
From tblA a inner join tblB b 
    on b.Col like '%'+a.Col+'%'
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1bde1/1)

Comment: The OP requested the data from tableB, not tableA, and you need to add a `DISTINCT` or, using the OP data, the 'cdefg' row will be returned twice

Answer (score 2):

One of these should work according to me

```
SELECT b.colA 
FROM TableB b join TableA a
WHERE colA like '%' + a.ColA + '%';


SELECT b.colA
FROM TableB b join TableA a
WHERE INSTR(b.colA, '{' + a.colA + '}') > 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT b.* FROM tblA a,tblB b
WHERE PATINDEX('%'+a.Col+'%',b.Col)>0
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/507d7/1)

I have searched for performance difference between PATINDEX and LIKE but not got a conclusive answer , some say PATINDEX is faster when indexing can't be used which is when pattern to be searched is enclosed within wildcard character eg '%'+a.Col+'%' while other post mention they can similar performance .

Perhaps some SO SQL Wizard can look in crystal ball and show us the light